# Error related to im2frame function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a sequence of images to a video. And I get the following error:

```
In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.close at 307
  In VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.delete at 256


Error using im2frame
Indexed movie data values must be legal colormap indices:
1.0 <= value <= length(colormap) for double-precision movie data, and 0 <=
value <= length(colormap)-1 for uint8 movie data

Error in VideoStabilization1 (line 134)
   writeVideo(writerObj,im2frame(I,cmap));
```

How should I resolve it?

I am using the following code line to write the video:

```
 writeVideo(writerObj,im2frame(I,cmap));
```

`I` is a colored image.

Comment: What's the range of the pixels intensity value in your video?

Answer (score 1):

Its a colored video and the pixel intensity for rgb on an average range between 0-250